# PUT request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, api

I am trying to make PUT request with ajax to update Rental object. Here is the ajax request. Note that `img.attr("data-rental-id")` works just fine.

```
$("#rentals").on("click", ".js-update", function () {
                    var img = $(this);
                    var vm = {};
                    vm.id = parseInt(img.attr("data-rental-id"));
                    vm.dateReturned = new Date(); 
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to mark this rental as returned?", function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/api/newRentals/" + img.attr("data-rental-id"),
                                type: "PUT",
                                data: vm,
                                success: function () {
                                    alert('Updated');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Here is my API Update method:

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateRental(UpdatedRentalDto UpdatedRentalDto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    var rentalInDb = _context.Rentals.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == UpdatedRentalDto.Id);

    if (rentalInDb == null)
        return NotFound();

    Mapper.Map(UpdatedRentalDto, rentalInDb);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```

And finally my DTO:

```
public class UpdatedRentalDto
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateReturned { get; set; }
}
```

Everything seems fine in theory, however, when I try to run it I get:

```
HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)PUT - http://localhost:57265/api/newRentals/1
```

Does that mean something is wrong with data variable vm? What's the mistake?

Comment: I believe that this is case sensitive, try to put your vm variable like this: vm.Id = parseInt(img.attr("data-rental-id"));
                    vm.DateReturned = new Date();

Comment: I use settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); so it should not be. But I tried and it did not work. Thanks for suggestion though!

Comment: ¿Can you put in your ajax call: contentType: json ? Probablly the data is sent as text/plain and thats why your API cannot read it.

Comment: Also send your data in the "data" key of your ajax call as JSON.stringify(vm)

Comment: The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the datetime formats of javascrip - /C#. If you do new date in javascript you get (in my browser version: Thu Jul 19 2018 12:31:40 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time). You sent this to the server and it probably can't be parsed into the DateTime field of c#.

1) Add reference to NewtonSoft.Json to your c# project

2) Add a DateFormatConverter class, here is my sample

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        public DateFormatConverter(string format)
        {
            DateTimeFormat = format;
            Culture = new CultureInfo("nl-BE"); //use this to have CET time !
        }
    }
```

2) In your dto, you can use this attribute where you can define (use a datetime format you want)

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")]
```

3) In javascript add a reference to moment.js (a very popular date/time handling library)

4) Use the format function of momentJS to format your datetime before sending to server